# How to add array values in CHtml::activeDropDownList in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to add $cluster1 values to CHtml::activeDropDownList

```
$cluster_name_models = new ClusterForm();
$records = $cluster_name_models->get_list('grade');
$cluster_details=$records['0']['grade'];
$cluster1=explode(';',$cluster_details);
$cluster1=Array ( [0] => JMC [1] => MMC [2] => SMC );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that grade is the name of the related model's attribute

```
  $cluster_name_models = new ClusterForm();
  $records = $cluster_name_models->get_list('grade');
  $cluster_details=$records['0']['grade'];
  $cluster1=explode(';',$cluster_details);



  echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,
                                  'grade',
                                  $cluster1,
                                  array('empty'=>'Select Option'));
```

Comment: i have get array like $cluster1=Array ( [0] => JMC [1] => MMC [2] => SMC ); after explode how to make it comma separated

Comment: If you explode  then you don't need  setting  (you have already an array).. answer updated